# How to check for NaN in XSLT?

Tags: xslt, xpath

How do I check in XPath / XSLT whether a certain value is NaN?

One way of doing it is `string($x) = 'NaN'`, but maybe there is a nicer / more efficient solution - something like JavaScript's `isNaN` function?

Solutions in XSLT 1 and XSLT 3 are welcome.

Comment: I think the FAQ idiom is `number($x) != number($x)`, in XPath 4 you might get a function https://qt4cg.org/branch/master/xpath-functions-40/Overview-diff.html#func-is-NaN

Comment: I personally think `string($x) = 'NaN` is probably the simplest practical solutiion today.

Comment: @MichaelKay This isn't a solution at all, because the string `"NaN"` is not equal to `xs:double("NaN")`, and `string("NaN") = "NaN"` . For a correct solution, see my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

> How do I check in XPath / XSLT whether a certain value is NaN?

Evaluating the following XPath 2.0+ expression must produce `true()` :

```
$x instance of xs:double and $x ne $x
```

Answer (score 0):

> One way of doing it is `string($x) = 'NaN'`

I believe the correct expression in XSLT 1.0 is:

```
string(number($x))='NaN'
```

Or, as already stated in the comments, you can use:

```
number($x) != number($x)
```

Comment: Sheesh, I have only now noticed: this question was asked almost 3 years ago!!